# Hosting Static Site on S3: Server DNS address could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static-site

What are some things I could look at to troubleshoot my static site on s3 intermittently showing `server DNS address could not be found` errors? It works most of the time but now having issues with the page not opening.

Comment: Sounds like misconfigured DNS.  We'll need your domain name for any meaningful troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using target DNS and not IP for the bucket. A
WS constantly changing IP.
The best way to use it through route53 as ALIAS but can cost a little bit.

Similar problem on aws forum that left unanswered. 
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231657

I guess you have this already but I'll mention it anyway:
If you are using a custom domain, make sure you enter exact domain name for your bucket name: mydomain.com